# Application Insights automation

Tags: azure, automation, azure-application-insights

I use application insights integrated in VS 2015 and monitor server and client telemetry. But I configure app insights only for one instance of my web site.

How can i automatize creating application insights instances with equal parameters (alert rules, tests...)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this you would need to use Azure Resource Manager (ARM) templates. There are some good links you can find on the Azure docs like below.

Basic Steps

1. Export resource group with insights components you want to clone
2. Parameterize the names of the components, alerts and webtests
3. Change the URLs of the webtests
4. Remove the alerts with custom metrics (they won't exist and will fail)

Example web app template with AI

https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-web-app-sql-database/azuredeploy.json#L266-L416

Deployment Documentation

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/resource-group-overview/#template-deployment